# Latest Autonumeric is allowing decimal point even if decimalPlaces set to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autonumber

I have requirement to allow whole numbers for the input textboxes, I do have the requirement to have currency symbol along with commas. I have used the latest version of autonumeric js.

I have set the decimalPlaces property to 0 but still it is allowing me press the dot once and upon further keypress dot is being removed. I want make the dot not be pressed at the first place if the decimalPlace property is set to 0

below is the snnipet along with JS fiddle link. Looking for any sort of help on this

```
AutoNumeric.multiple('.testInput', 
{ currencySymbol: '$', decimalPlaces: 0, unformatOnSubmit: true, modifyValueOnWheel: false });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpomn0d2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `decimalPlaces` value by using `getPredefinedOptions()` function and specify the `integer.decimalPlaces` property:

```
var places = AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().integer.decimalPlaces;
```

Then use its value to prevent non-numeric symbols inserted on `keydown` event:

```
$('.testInput').keydown(function (e) {
    var places = AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().integer.decimalPlaces;

    if (places == 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))
    {
        // prevent symbol insertion
        return false;
    }

    // other stuff
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2y7o6bqw/)

Reference: [AutoNumeric static methods](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#static-methods)